# Notation for operations in algebraic structures, e.g. groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, terminology, translation-request

Since I'm learning Math in a non-mother language I have some difficulty understanding a concept even if I use English/Arabic.

Problem: Understanding Groups in Algebraic Structure.
Way to help me understand: "Soit $E$ un ensemble non vide, on appelle loi de composition interne sur $E$ toute application $\Psi$ de $E^2$ dans $E$. On note le resultat de l'operation $\Psi$ de $x$ par $y$ par un symbole, par example $\Psi(x,y) = x ⊕ y$"

Questions: What is the use of $\Psi$ in that position '$\Psi(x,y)$' and is "$Ψ(x,y) = (G, +)$" **($G$ and $+$ are the most used symbols in the tutorials in youtube)**

Comment: It's a Greek letter representing a function.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

$\Psi(x,y)=(G,+)$ is nonsense; I am certain the authors did not write that. You could define a group $G$ as a triplet $(G,\Psi;e)$ though. However:

Really, a group "is" (can be defined as) a nonempty set with a function $\Psi:G\times G\to G$ satisfying certain assumptions. This function is sometimes called "the group law" or "the group multiplication". However, *standard* function notation isn't very human-friendly here: it's really cumbersome to work with expressions like $\Psi(x,\Psi(\Psi(y,z),a))$ but $x+y+z+a$ is great! So we prefer to use a simple symbol such as "$+$" or $\cdot$ (or just no symbol at all!) to denote the 'action' of $\Psi$. This is what your text is saying: instead of using $\Psi(x,y)$, it's *convenient* to rewrite this as $x+y$ or $x\oplus y$ .. whatever. The symbol used doesn't matter mathematically (but it does if you want your conventions to match those of other people). For example, "$+$" makes me think the group is Abelian, whereas "$\cdot$" (so $\Psi(x,y)=x\cdot y$) makes me think of a more general, possibly anabelian group.

Comment: 1. "You could define a group G as a triplet (G, Ψ;e)" Can you explain this more simply?

2. So, basically, the Ψ tends to represent "a logo or a name to my function which is G x G -> G"

3. "Ψ(x,Ψ(Ψ(y,z),a)) but x+y+z+a" This is more simplified thanks but how can you read "Ψ(x,Ψ(Ψ(y,z),a))"?

Comment: @Mavlock There are a few ways to define a group. One possible way is this: "A group is a triple $(G,\psi,e)$ where $G$ is a set, $e\in G$ and $\psi:G\times G\to G$ is a function **and** we have: $\psi(x,\psi(y,z))=\psi(\psi(x,y),z)$ and $\psi(x,e)=x=\psi(e,x)$ for all $x\in G$ and for all $x\in G$ there exists a $y\in G$ with $\psi(x,y)=e=\psi(y,x)$."

Comment: Well, $\psi(x,\psi(\psi(y,z),a))$ makes sense in terms of function notation. It's just hard to read

Comment: Indeed it is, so, am I allowed to use any symbol/sign to notate instead of Psi(ψ)?

Comment: @Mavlock Yeah! as long as others understand you / you define your notation

Comment: Is "anabelian" synonymous of "non-abelian", @FShrike? Or rather "anabelian"="possibly non-abelian" (kind of "unknown")?

Comment: @citadel I *thought* it was synonymous with nonabelian but, looking it up, in some technical contexts it means a stronger thing. Oh well.